# monthlyRainfall.filter(...).first is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine

https://code.earthengine.google.com/18914d58d2f193bf206e108774902ce5

```
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)

...

var monthlyRainfall = months.map(function(month) {
    var filtered = monthlyCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
    var monthlyMean = filtered.mean()
    return monthlyMean.set('month', month)
})

...

var deviation = months.map(function(month) {
  var longTermMean = ee.Image(monthlyRainfall
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first())
  var monthlyObserved = ee.Image(observedRainfall
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first())
  var deviation = (monthlyObserved.subtract(longTermMean)
    .divide(longTermMean)).multiply(100)
    .set('month', month)
  return deviation
})
```

I am getting an error or line no. 88 in the link that I have mentioned above.

`Line 88: monthlyRainfall.filter(...).first is not a function`

the solution which i  found for this problem is to use ee.Image. But even after using it, I am facing the same error. Please help me how to get through it.

Answer (score 0):

`monthlyRainfall` is an `ee.List`, not an `ee.ImageCollection`. They're similar in some ways, but `ee.List` doesn't have a `.first()` operation (instead you would write `.get(0)`).

Filters also work differently on lists and collections. In this case, in order to make it work the way you want, you should convert your List to an ImageCollection. Change

```js
var monthlyRainfall = months.map(function(month) {
    var filtered = monthlyCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month))
    var monthlyMean = filtered.mean()
    return monthlyMean.set('month', month)
})
```

to apply `ee.ImageCollection(...)`, which will convert the List of Images into an ImageCollection:

```js
var monthlyRainfall = ee.ImageCollection(months.map(function(month) {
    var filtered = monthlyCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month));
    var monthlyMean = filtered.mean();
    return monthlyMean.set('month', month);
}));
```